# Export dictionnary in JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a JSON file (stored in database.txt) I want to modify using python dictionary in method addEvent():

```
def addEvent(eventName, start, end, place):
    newdict={} #make a new dictionnary
    newdict["NAME"]=eventName
    newdict["START"]=start
    newdict["END"]=end
    newdict["place"]=place
try:
    with open("database.txt",'r') as file:
        content=file.read()
        dict=json.loads(content) #make dictionnary with original JSON file
        liste.append(newdict) 
        dico["event"]=liste  #combine 2dictionnaries
    with open("database.txt", 'w') as file:
        file.write(str(dico))  #save my new JSON file


except:
    ...
```

**My problem:**
I can run this method only one time, second time I receive an error message:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

addEvent() method modify my database.txt file: it doesn't incule double quotes anymore but accents so i can't use `dict=json.loads(content)` second time

**My question** Did I correctly save my JSON file ? How can I keep my JSON format in my database.txt file (keep double quotes) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You produced *Python syntax* by converting the object with `str()`; Python strings can use either single or double quotes. To produce a JSON string, use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
file.write(json.dumps(dico))
```

The `json` module has variants of `json.loads()` and `json.dumps()` that work directly with files; there is no need to read or write yourself, just use the function names without the trailing `s` on file objects directly:

```
with open("database.txt", 'r') as file:
    d = json.load(file)
```

and

```
with open("database.txt", 'w') as file:
    json.dump(dico, file)
```

Comment: Thank you, you help me to understand more about JSON files

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
file.write(str(dico))  #save my new JSON file
```

Use [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) instead:

```
file.write(json.dumps(dico))  #save my new JSON file
```